# Display javascript button along with the object it belongs to

Tags: javascript, button, javascript-objects

I have a constructor in javascript which constructs new book items. And that constructor has a prototype method. That method attaches a button to each object thats created by the constructor.
Now I want to display lets my first object information and then display the button related to it underneath it but I can't seem to do that. I can only displayed the button by using the "appendChild" tag. See the code below:

```
  // the prototype to create and attach the button to the "item" object
   Item.prototype.createBtn = function(item)
    {

        // where I display the object data. for example title, price.
        var ItemDiv = document.getElementById('itemsList');
        // where I display my buttons
        var bask = document.getElementById('buttonsList');

         // I create a new button. this.btn belongs to my constructor
         this.btn = document.createElement("button");

         this.btn.setAttribute("style", "width: 200px; height: 45px; background-color:#27ae60; margin-right: 500px; padding: 20px;");

              // attach an event listener to my button
              this.btn.addEventListener("click", function(){myBasket(item);});


             // display the object data to the page

             ans +=  '<div>' +"Title: "+ this.title + '</div>';
             ans +=  '<div>' +"Description: "+ this.description + '</div>';
             ans +=  '<div>' +"Price: "+ this.price +'</li><br>';
             ans += "<br>";


             // display the buttons into the "bask div"
             bask.appendChild(this.btn);

             // display the object data   
            ItemDiv.innerHTML = ans; 

        };

    function myBasket(item)
    {

       //do something

    }
```

Instead of the button being displayed into a different div I want the button to b displayed right below the object data for example:

```
title: book1
price: book1
description: book1
button here
```

My HTML:

```
<script src="basket.js"></script>
<script src="item.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="basket.css">
```

```
<h1>The Item List</h1>

<div id="ItemDiv" class="divOne">
<div id="itemsList" class="divTwo">
    <div id="test"></div>    
</div>
<div id="buttonsList" class="divThree"></div>


</div>
<div id="BasketDiv">
</div>
```

Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: So, you just want to append the button to the `ItemDiv`?

Comment: Can you share your markup? Any errors in the console?

Comment: I implemented that just now it kind-of worked. Its only displaying one button. and that button belongs to the last object constructed by the constructor. But if I do appendChild it displays all the buttons related to all objects constructed.  Apologies for my comment above I made a mistake in the code thats why the screen went blank. I apologise.

Comment: @DerekS no console errors and Ive added my markup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will append the button below the data. You were overwriting the html of `ItemDiv` instead of appending.

```
// display the object data    
ansNode = document.createTextNode(ans);
ItemDiv.appendChild(ansNode);

// append the button to the data div
ItemDiv.appendChild(this.btn);
```

Comment: Perfect!! Thank you for taking the time out to reply. This really helped me. Again thanks.